Large Production Build File Size in Laravel 6 (Mix) with Vue.js 2
I'm using Laravel 6 (Mix) and Vue.js 2 for my project. When I run the yarn prod command on the server, it generates a large production file, which significantly increases the load time of the website.
I've also added extract in my webpack.mix.js configuration to separate vendor files, but the file size issue persists.
The sizes of the generated files are:
/v2/js/vendor.js?id=4b6042a699ca621c856y - 1.9 MiB (27%)
/v2/js/app.js?id=0892f4497fbbbad7bbg4 - 652.2 KiB (9%)

Additionally, analysis tools show that nearly 50% of the content in these files is unused.
Here's my webpack.mix.js file:
require('laravel-mix-svg-vue');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');

mix.js("resources/v2/js/app.js", "public/v2/js").vue().svgVue({
    svgPath: 'resources/v2/assets/svg',
    extract: false,
    svgoSettings: [{ removeTitle: true }, { removeViewBox: false }, { removeDimensions: true }]
})
    .extract([
        'vue', 'vuex', 'vee-validate', 'lodash',
        'vuetify', 'feather-icons', 'dayjs',
        'tailwindcss', 'masonry-layout',
        'swiper', 'mapbox-gl', 'vue-awesome-swiper', '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw'
    ])
    .copyDirectory("resources/v2/assets/images", "public/v2/assets/images")
    .copyDirectory("resources/v2/assets/svg", "public/v2/assets/svg")
    .copyDirectory("resources/v2/assets/fonts", "public/v2/assets/fonts")
    .postCss("resources/v2/css/materialdesignicons.min.css", "public/v2/css")
    .postCss("resources/v2/css/app.css", "public/v2/css", [require('tailwindcss')])
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
        ]
    });

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: '[name].js?id=[contenthash]',
    },
});

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();

    const ASSET_URL = process.env.ASSET_URL + "/";

    mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
        return {
            plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env.ASSET_PATH": JSON.stringify(ASSET_URL)
            })], output: {
                publicPath: ASSET_URL
            }
        };
    });
}

How can I reduce the size of the production build file and optimize the loading time of my website? Any suggestions or improvements for my webpack.mix.js configuration are greatly appreciated!

"large" is subjective.  How large exactly?  Regardless, reducing the size will probably depend on what exactly is taking up so much space, but that would require knowledge of your specific app which we don't have.  You'll need to do some debugging on your own first.  Try webpack bundle analyzer. If there is a surprisingly large file in the app, the analyzer will point it out.
